# How to upload ZipFile to Dropbox using Python?

Tags: python, dropbox-api, python-zipfile

I am trying to upload a .zip file to Dropbox using the Dropbox API for python. But this method seems to fail. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
            if os.path.exists(zip_name):
                with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name,'r') as zf:
                    self.auth_client.put_file('/', zf, overwrite=True)
                    zf.close()
```

Error Message:

```
KeyError: 'There is no item named 8192 in the archive'
```

This error seems to propagate from the put_file method.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Don't you just want a regular `with open(zip_name, 'rb') as zf:`? Why open the zipfile?

Comment: @tdelaney, i tried the normal open file, doesn't work.

Comment: Where does it fail? What is the stack trace? I didn't see anything in the dropbox docs about opening using ZipFile and the `zf` object isn't an open file. The dropbox docs at https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python# say its just a file open in "rb" mode.

Comment: It fails in the innermost `data.readblock()` method which dropbox uses from requests or some url library.

Comment: I think the `open(filename,'rb')` worked. Thanks @tdelaney :-)